# Poisson distribution variance, probability, and mean.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ be the poisson random variable such that $\mathbb P(X=2)=9\mathbb P(X=4)+90\mathbb P(X=6)$.

a) Find the mean and variance of $X$.

b) Find $\mathbb P(X\geq1)$.

c) Find $\mathbb P(X\leq10)$.

For a), I need to turn each probability into its respective $p(x)$ form and solve for $\lambda$. I got that$\lambda$ was $1$ so therefore, the mean and variance should be $1$.

Now, for the second question, I have that $\mathbb P(X\geq 1)=1- \mathbb P(X<1)$. Am I to assume that $\lambda$ is still $1$? If so, is $1-\mathrm e^{-1}$ the correct answer for b)?

For c), I'm just lost here... it was asked to solve this problem through R programming language. Correct me if I'm wrong, but is is not just simply $\mathbb P(X \leq10)=1-\mathbb P(X>10)$? If so, I'd think that solving for $\mathbb P(X>10)$ would be plugging in `ppois(10,1)` into R, but I'm just getting $1$ as the output... that means a $100\%$ change of $\mathbb P(X>10)$... sorry if this question isn't what this MSE is for but if you know what I'm talking about, that'd be really helpful.

Comment: The is the second time today I've seen part (a) of this question posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\Pr(X=2) = 9\Pr(X=4) + 90\Pr(X=6)
$$
$$
\frac{\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda}}{2!} = 9\frac{\lambda^4 e^{-\lambda}}{4!} + 90 \frac{\lambda^6 e^{-\lambda}}{6!}
$$
Multiply both sides by $2e^\lambda/\lambda^2$:
$$
1 = \frac{9\lambda^2}{12} + \frac{90\lambda^4}{360} = \frac{3\lambda^2}{4} + \frac{\lambda^4}{4}
$$
$$
4 = 3\lambda^2+\lambda^4
$$
$$
(\lambda^2+4)(\lambda^2-1)=0
$$
Since $\lambda$ must be real and positive, we have $\lambda=1$.  From that, get the mean and variance and the probabilities from the usual formulas.